# Adding Polymer component attributes dynamically

Tags: polymer

I have a polymer component included inside another polymer component like this

```
<dom-module id="custom-component2">
    <template>
        <custom-component1 id="component1" type="abc" config="xyz"></custom-component1>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'custom-component2',
    properties: {

    },
    ready: function() {

    },
    init: function() {

    }
});
</script>
```

Is there anyway I can add the attributes such as type, config for my "custom-component1" dynamically like -

```
<dom-module id="custom-component2">
    <template>
        <custom-component1 id="component1"></custom-component1>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'custom-component2',
    properties: {

    },
    ready: function() {
        self.$.component1.type = "abc";
        self.$.component1.config = "xyz";
    }
});
</script>
```

or can I pass these options as a whole as an object?

Could someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<dom-module id="custom-component2">
    <template>
        <custom-component1 id="component1"></custom-component1>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'custom-component2',
    properties: {

    },
    attached: function() {
        this.$.component1.type = "abc";
        this.$.component1.config = "xyz";
    }
});
</script>
```

Using data-binding with an object:

```
<dom-module id="custom-component2">
    <template>
        <custom-component1 id="component1" data={{_data}}></custom-component1>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'custom-component2',
    properties: {
        _data:{
           type: Object,
           value: function(){ 
                  return {type:"abc", config:"xyz"};
           }
        },
    },
});
</script>
```